# Why do I need the static keyword here?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Info {

    
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int n1,n2;
        
        System.out.print("Enter n1: ");
        n1 = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Enter n2: ");
        n2 = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println(sumTotal(n1,n2));
        
    }
    
    public static int sumTotal(int n1sum, int n2sum) { // *why static includes here*
        return n1sum+n2sum;
        
    }
}
```

I don't understand why do I need to put static in here?

Some other codes with return statement doesn't need static, like this one. So why?

```
public class FirstProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); // for scanning
    
        int age;
        
        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        age = userInput.nextInt(); 

        var a = new FirstProgram(); 
        a.userAge(age); 
                        
    }
    
    public int userAge(int age1) 
    {                            
        if ( age1 < 18 )                                          
        {
            System.out.println("You are a YOUNG!");
        }
        
        else if (age1 > 18 && age1 <=25)
        {
            System.out.println("Young adult! ");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wise!");

        }
        return age1;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why do I need to put static in here.

Java does not allow calling non-`static` method from a `static` method directly.

> Some other codes with return statement doesn't need static, like this
> one. so whyy?

This is how (i.e. using the instance of the class) Java allows you to call a non-`static` method from a `static` method.

Learn more about `static` keyword [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).